# Adding an attachimage setting in paramsGroup attribute in visual composer

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer, wpbakery

I am attempting to create a `paramsGroup` attribute in my `settings.json` file.

I have defined it like this:

```
 "bars": {
    "type": "paramsGroup",
    "access": "public",
    "value": {
      "value": [
        {
          "title": "Content Item",
          "value": 80,
          "color": "#333333"
        }
      ]
    },
    "options": {
      "label": "General",
      "title": "Content Item",
      "groupDefaultTile": "I dont know",
      "settings": {
        "title": {
          "type": "string",
          "access": "public",
          "value": "Plumbing Service",
          "options": {
            "label": "Indicator Text"
          }
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "range",
          "access": "public",
          "value": "70",
          "options": {
            "label": "Value"
          }
        },
        "color": {
          "type": "color",
          "access": "public",
          "value": "#50E3C2",
          "options": {
            "label": "Bar color"
          }
        },
        "imaget": {
          "type": "attachimage",
          "access": "public",
          "value": ["image-1.png", "image-2.png", "image-3.png"],
          "options": {
            "label": "Images",
            "multiple": true,
            "url": false
          }
        },
        "_paramGroupEditFormTab1": {
          "type": "group",
          "access": "public",
          "value": ["title", "value", "color", "image"],
          "options": {
            "label": "General"
          }
        },
        "metaEditFormTabs": {
          "type": "group",
          "access": "public",
          "value": ["_paramGroupEditFormTab1"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

I am able to use the `attachimage` setting outside of this paramsGroup but for some reason this does not work as part of the paramsGroup type.  Has anyone ever attempted using a paramsGroup in this manner?

this is the error I am getting:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'link')`

[image: e is undefined here]

After adding some debuggers to the VC code, I noticed that when it attempts to parse through the settings object, it chokes because the variable being accessed is undefined.  am I missing a key attribute I should be including to make this valid?